# Openlayers and IE11 bad GET perfomance

Tags: get, request, openlayers, internet-explorer-11

I have a really weird problem with Openlayers and IE11: I try to get a layer from a WMS server but Openlayers/IE11 doesn't perform any GET request to get the map image (Chrome and Firefox do). I captured the network traffic with the IE11 F12 Developer tool and the request to the WMS server appears anulled. The funny thing is that if I type the requested URL in the browser (not using the WMS layer with OpenLayers), I get the image... Any help?

Detalis:

WMS URL  returned by Openlayers: (it works in the browser, the map image is returned in IE11):

http://www.idee.es/wms/PNOA/PNOA?LAYERS=PNOA&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG%3A25829&BBOX=523505.22778579,4692620.49881,527007.25852459,4696122.5295488&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

Openlayers code (it doesn't get the image in IE11):

```
 new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("PNOA", "http://www.idee.es/wms/PNOA/PNOA", {
          layers:'PNOA',


         transparent:true
     }, {
         isBaseLayer: true
     })
```

Comment: Really strange. No error at all in dev console?

Comment: Any error. The only error I found is that the GET request is avoided by the browser...

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered what the problem was: I had my apache server configured to work on port 8081, for some reason it seams that IE11 doesn't work properly requesting external resources from a different port than 80. I've changed apache's port to 80 and everything works porperly. :)